# Regular expression to filter desired rows from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, filter

I am working with fairly messy data: a tariff table with the following form:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data1 = np.array([u'Free (A, B, KR, FR), 5% (JP)', u'Free (A, B, FR), 5% (JP, KR))'])
data2 = np.array(['10101010', '10101020'])
data = {'hscode': data2, 'tariff' : data1}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['hscode', 'tariff'])
```

The first row shows that the tariff is zero for countries (A, B, KR, FR) and 5% for JP, and the second row shows that it is zero for A, B, FR while 5 % for JP and KR.

I want to find the tariff rate of country 'KR' for each row, so that I could have the following table:

'hscode' 'tariff'

10101010 0%

10101020 5%

So, I want to find the tariff rate for the county code 'KR' in each cell.

Comment: can you explain more clearly how's that data2 related to data1 and what's relationship with KR and (A,B,KR, FR)?

Comment: Hi Anzel, data2 is the 'hamonized tariff code' and the data1 shows the actual tariff rate for each countries. (A, B, KR, FR, JP) all denote countires, and I want to find the tariff rate for a specific country, KR. Thanks.

Comment: I just posted an answer that does not use regular expressions. Are regular expressions mandatory? Because you just state them in the title.

Comment: Thanks, Fabian. I am trying to study re, as I encounter this kind of messy text data frequently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use apply with regex:

```
## -- End pasted text --

In [133]: import re

In [134]: df
Out[134]: 
     hscode                         tariff
0  10101010   Free (A, B, KR, FR), 5% (JP)
1  10101020  Free (A, B, FR), 5% (JP, KR))

In [135]: df['tariff'].apply(lambda x: ''.join(re.findall(r'.*(Free|\d+%).*\bKR\b', x)))
Out[135]: 
0    Free
1      5%
Name: tariff, dtype: object
```

Explain: within tariff, capture either "Free" or "x%" if string contains "KR".

You may create a function to dynamically set "KR" as a lookup variable.

Comment: Anzel, you are my angel! This works very well, but I still need to study regular expressions. I don't understand how this code works. It looks like it is trying to find (Free|\d+%) in x, but I don't know what two stars(*) and a dot(.) do in this expression and. I also don't know how this code handles the parenthesis. But thanks so much! I will study this more!!

Comment: @JohnShin Not a problem :) the .* (dot star) means zero or more of any characters (which is anything really) and \b[string]\b means the whole thing must contains the full [string], take it as startswith - endswith

Comment: @JohnShin the regex I used is basically a pattern matching saying OK -- with or without anything at front .* without brackets (i am not capturing it), it has to be either "Free" or "x%" with brackets (I want to capture the value), again there can be anything between the strings it must contain, ie. "KR"... so at the end you're only capturing (...) <- the thing in brackets

Comment: Thank you for your explanations. It looks like regular expression is more powerful than I imagined. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @JohnShin, it is, but always try to solve this in the simplest way you can think of, before moving to regex. As sometimes simple if/then will do just fine and you can rid of unnecessary overhead

Answer (score 0):

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    data1 = np.array([u'Free (A, B, KR, FR), 5% (JP)', u'Free (A, B, FR), 5% (JP, KR))'])
    data2 = np.array(['10101010', '10101020'])

    df = []
    for i, element in enumerate(data1):
        free, five = element.lstrip('Free (').rstrip(')').split('), 5% (')
        for country in free.split(', '):
            row = [data2[i], 'Free', country]
            df.append(row)
        for country in five.split(', '):
            row = [data2[i], '5%', country]
            df.append(row)
    df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ['hscode', 'tariff', 'country'])
    print df.query('country == "KR"')
```

gives

```
     hscode tariff country
2  10101010   Free      KR
9  10101020     5%      KR
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, what if there are multiple tariff rates, i.e., if could be 4%, 5%, 1%, etc... I have rows more than 20,000. Thanks.